# plotting a graph using R plugin in PyCharm

Tags: r, pycharm

Is anyone familiar with the R Plugin for PyCharm?

My histogram won't plot. There is nothing in the R plugin documentation that talks about R Graphics.

Also, is there a way of turning off echo so that print() does not have to be explicitly used to view results in the console?

Thank you all!